# The 02Micro SD card reader is not recognised by Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: card-reader

My Dell Vostro 1510 has an internal SD card reader that works well under Windows XP, but it is not recognised by Ubuntu. `ls /dev/sd*` only fetches lines related to the HDD, same for commands `fd` and `fdisk`. The following is the output of `lspci`:

```
08:05.2 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Integrated MMC/SD Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Integrated MMC/SD Controller
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 22
    Memory at f8202800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
```

Rebooting with a SD card inserted does not help.  Dell does not supply any device driver for Linux. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Run into the same problem today – and found the solution [on another page](http://www.0xf8.org/2016/01/workaround-for-broken-o2-micro-sd-card-reader-support-since-linux-kernel-version-4-1-8/).

There was a Kernel-change, that opened a Bug with the SD Module. To fix it, it is necessary to change some options of the Kernel Module. First of all, test the setting by executing these commands on the terminal:

```
sudo rmmod sdhci_pci sdhci_acpi sdhci
sudo modprobe sdhci debug_quirks2="0x10000"
sudo modprobe sdhci_pci
```

First line unloads the sdhci module and dependents, the second line is setting the needed option and the third line reloads the modules.

Now test, if your system recognizes inserted SD cards. My system instantly did.

If all succeeded till now, we have to push the option as a default – therefor execute this command as su:

```
echo "options sdhci debug_quirks2=0x10000" >> /etc/modprobe.d/sdhci.conf
```

Cheers =)

Comment: thanks Martin,

but it does not work even if the three commands are accepted.

Comment: The three commands work for me, but adding the sdhci.conf file is not enough to prevent losing the debug_quirks after reboot.

Comment: The missing step is to run "sudo update-initramfs -k all -u" this will then update the runtime kernel and modules that are loaded at boot time.  It will also be picked up in future kernel updates by adding the file to /etc/modprobe.d/sdhci.conf

Comment: Also if 0x10000 does work simply try 0x4 instead

Comment: I got my 128GB card working with 0x2 which does have an impact on speed I hear, but 0x10000 didn't work for me